# Laravel Get all child node count with condition

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am using [Laravel5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) in my application. In this i have one table name users and schema of user table as follow.

```
id          Name         Parane_id     Node
1           ABC          0             
2           XYZ          1              L
3           DFS          1              R
4           GJK          2              L
5           DSG          3              L
6           FAF          4              R
7           KES          2              R
```

I want to count of all user left side on user 1 (i.e 2,4,6,7) so count is 4.

same as if i want right side of 2 then it will return 7 so count is 1.

how can be this possible using `Laravel Eloquent`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "all user left side on user 1"?

Comment: Can you provide more explanation about left side and right?

Comment: @mdamia It just like every people have two leg, one is left and other is right

so if i have child then i will add them as left or right. So basically every parent has maximum two child, and child has sub child and so on.

so in my example you can see user `ABC` has two child 2,3 in which `XYZ` is left side (Node : L means left and R means Right) and `DFS` is right side.

Hope you will got it or let me if not.

Comment: For more understanding just check the image

http://imgur.com/01JRusx

Answer (score 0):

You want to count your tree nodes on certain condition which in this case is the left children of a node.

Define the children for your `User`. Then create a function to traverse your children tree and do counting.

```
class User extends Model {

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function countChildren($node = null)
    {
        $query = $this->children();
        if (!empty($node))
        {
            $query = $query->where('node', $node);
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($query->get() as $child)
        {
            $count += $child->countChildren() + 1; // Plus 1 to count the direct child
        }
        return $count;
    }

}
```

To count the left children of user id 1.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$count = $user->countChildren('L');
```

Comment: is there any better way to count the child in laravel?